# Passing a variable to target a specific array

Tags: jquery

Hopefully this is a simple question, but I can't seem to get to work.

I'm trying to pass a variable to access a specific array and hide that array's contents.

In this example $prodCat = labialWire.  In the .each() I am trying to replace labialWire with $prodCat and hide those objects but it's not working.

jquery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteLiRadio', function() {
    var $prodCat    = $(this).data('prodcat'),
        $ul         = "#upperConfirmUl",
        unchecked   = new Array();

    console.log($prodCat);
    $("li[data-prodcat='" + $prodCat + "']").remove();
    $('form[data-caturl="' + $prodCat + '"]').trigger('reset');
    $($ul).listview( "refresh" );
    $($ul).trigger( "updatelayout");

    $('form[data-caturl="' + $prodCat + '"] input:not(:checked)').each(function () {
        unchecked.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    //console.log(unchecked);

    $.each(unchecked, function (i, val) {
        labialWire[val] && labialWire[val].hide();/*Replace labialWire with $prodCat*/
    });
});
```

Really appreciate any help!

If it helps, Im getting an undefined response using $prodCat[val].

Comment: @JamesMontagne haha, it's nothing of that nature.

Comment: What is `labialWire`, where do you declare it?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It's a global array outside this function.

Comment: what is it containing? Can you post the declaration of this var?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon The array contains Raphael objects.  The code works if I specifically write labialWire but when I replace it with $prodCat(which = labialWire) it doesn't function.

Answer (score 1):

If `labialWire` is a global variable (array):

```
if (window["labialWire"])
  window["labialWire"].[val].hide();
```

or using a string variable with value "labialWire":

```
if (window[$prodCat])
  window[$prodCat].[val].hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am trying to avoid a bunch of conditional statements for scalability.